# mono 2.10 under windows vista sp1 HttpWebRequest always throws time out exception

Tags: mono, httpwebrequest

HttpWebRequest always throws time out exception then run in mono 2.10 under Windows Vista SP1 32bit. The same request completes successfully then run under Microsoft .Net in the same machine. Here  follows code:

```
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false";
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    Console.WriteLine(request.GetResponse());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**update:**

version of mono:

```
c:\Program Files\Mono-2.10\bin>mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10 (tarball)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       normal
    Notification:  Thread + polling
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Comment: Please somebody add new tag mono 2.10 ...

Comment: This is MonoDevelop bug, then run from command line program runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce with Mono 2.10 on Windows 7 x64.

c:\Users\Owner\Development\monobugs>C:\Mono-2.10\bin\mono.exe -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10 (tarball)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           normal
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notification:  Thread + polling
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)

c:\Users\Owner\Development\monobugs>C:\Mono-2.10\bin\mono.exe http.exe
System.Net.HttpWebResponse

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it'll be relevant here but I've just come across the same issue (well, same symptoms at any rate) and found it was caused by using HttpWebRequest from a thread which had been created in native code.  (This thread had later run a callback which PInvoked managed code.)

My problem was fixed by creating a worker thread in managed code and shuffling all uses of HttpWebRequest into that.

I've posted this as a [mono bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3374)

Answer (score 0):

In Mono 2.10.2 calling paypal Timeout exception occurs if this code is used:

```
HttpWebRequest objRequest = 
  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
objRequest.Timeout =15000;
objRequest.Method = "POST";
objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
using (StreamWriter myWriter = new 
  StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            myWriter.Write(strPost);
```

causes exception at GetRequestStream() :

```
    System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x0005f] in 
    /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-                2.10.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:752
      at NVPAPICaller.HttpCall (System.String NvpRequest) [0x00000] in         <filename 
    unknown>:0

    --------------------------------------------------------------------        ------------
    Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.2 (tarball Mon Apr         18 
    18:57:39 UTC 2011); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

You should downgrade to Mono 2.10 first version, it look like this happens in 2.10.2 only.